# ASP.NET State Server is hanging

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state

I am using `ASP.NET State Server`, while using the website, following message occurs occasionally

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> ```
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
> ```

As soon as the `ASP.NET State Server` service is restarted it gets fixed and of course all sessions are killed. 
If In-Proc is used then nothing like this happens.
What could be the reason?

Comment: What error u are getting Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" lockItem="true" />
  <trace enabled="false" localOnly="true"/>
<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true"/>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i was trapped in a recursion.

And, the funny thing about this is that FireFox didn't let me know because FF was terminating the request and returning with the error. While, Internet Explorer kept running which made me think what is wrong and why it is taking that much time!!! and i found the recursion.